# Hybrid program (.asm + .cpp): modify small math program's code to include float input

Tags: c, assembly, floating-point, hybrid

(Intel x86. TASM and BorlandC compilers, and TLINK used.)

In `main1.cpp`  the program takes `int` input (until you input a number smaller than -999999), puts it into an array `x[]`, puts the number of inputs into array's 0th element, sends array's pointer to `f1.asm`, adds the numbers, and returns the result to `main1.cpp` so it can be displayed.

How to modify it so it will include floating-point numbers as input?

My specific problems:

1. The location of the input's offset in `f1.asm` changes when I turn `int` into `float`, and I can't find it ;
2. Math operations on floats in `.asm`.

(I couldn't really comprehend explanation on `.asm` floats I found elsewhere.)

Thank you in advance.

**main1.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

extern "C" int f1( int* x );

int main()
{   

    int x[100], i ;

    for( i = 1 ; x[i-1]>=-999999 ; i++ )
    {
         cout << "x[" << i << "] = " ;
         cin  >> x[i] ;                // Input elements while they're >= -999999
    }

    x[0] = i-1 ; // 0th array element gets the number of inputed elements

    cout<<"\nSum of inputs = " << f1(x) ;

    return 0;
}
```

**f1.asm:**

```
.model SMALL, C

.data

.code

PUBLIC f1
f1 PROC

    push    BP
    mov BP,SP       ; SP contains input from the c++ function

    mov ax,[bp+4]       ; get the address of the array
    mov bp, ax          ; BP now points to the array's 0th element
                ; (which is the the number of the to-be-added c++ inputs)

    mov di, 0
    mov ax, 0

    mov cx, [bp]    ; number of unputs gets stored in cx
    dec cx

    add bp, 2       ; Move bp to point at the next number -- the first c++ input

loop1:
    mov bx, [bp]      
    add ax, bx      ; add the input to the growing pile

    add bp, 2       ; move the offset to point to the next input
    inc di      ; increase the Additions Counter

    cmp di, cx      ; if you add up all of the c++ inputs, exit loop
    jne loop1

    pop BP
    ret

f1 ENDP

.stack
db 100(?)

END
```

Comment: It's so old, nobody remembers what  the convention for floats was :) Disassemble your C code to see where it places the arguments and where it expects the result.

Comment: Changing the type of the parameter of `f1` from `int *` to `float *` doesn't change where its passed on the stack. It will still be a 16-bit pointer located  in `[bp + 4]`. What changes is that now it instead of pointing to 16-bit integers it points to 32-bit floats. This means they won't fit into 16-bit registers and they won't work with the integer arithmetic instructions (DEC and ADD). Also, you can make things a bit easier on yourself by passing the number of elements in the array as a second parameter.

Comment: @Ross I know of (and used previously) the `.386` declaration in `.asm` which allows using the `eax, ebx, ecx, ... etc.` registers. Besides what you said, and (i'm guessing) increasing `bp` by 4 instead of 2 as I move to subsequent inputs, how should I additionally modify the code to make `float` calculations? I've read of `fadd` and other float-commands, but I don't know if I can straight-up substitute the `add` command with it.

Comment: You can't substitute ADD with FADD. The floating point "FPU" instructions use the floating pointer register stack, which is a different set of registers from the general purpose ones, and works like a stack. You're going to have to do some reading in order to learn how the 8087 FPU instructions work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example as addition to the comments of Ross Ridge.

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream.h>

extern "C" {
    int f1( int* );
    float f2( float* );
}

int main()
{
    int x1[100]   = {5,3,4,5,6};
    float x2[100] = {5,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.5};

    cout << "Sum of x1 = " << f1(x1) << endl;
    cout << "Sum of x2 = " << f2(x2) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**f1.asm:**

```
.model SMALL, C

LOCALS @@
PUBLIC f1, f2

.code
f1 PROC

    push BP
    mov BP,SP           ; SP contains input from the c++ function

    mov ax,[bp+4]       ; get the address of the array
    mov bp, ax          ; BP now points to the array's 0th element
                        ; (which is the the number of the to-be-added c++ inputs)

    mov di, 0
    mov ax, 0

    mov cx, [bp]        ; number of unputs gets stored in cx
    dec cx
    add bp, 2           ; Move bp to point at the next number -- the first c++ input

    @@loop1:
    mov bx, [bp]
    add ax, bx          ; add the input to the growing pile
    add bp, 2           ; move the offset to point to the next input
    inc di              ; increase the Additions Counter
    cmp di, cx          ; if you add up all of the c++ inputs, exit loop
    jne @@loop1

    pop BP
    ret

f1 ENDP

f2 PROC
    push bp
    mov bp, sp
    sub sp, 2                   ; Space for a local temporary variable

    mov bx,[bp+4]               ; Get the address of the array into BX
                                ; (BP is used otherwise)

    fld dword ptr ss:[bx]       ; Load the first float
    fistp word ptr [bp-2]       ;     and store it as int
    mov cx, [bp-2]              ; Length of array
    dec cx

    mov di, 0
    fldz                        ; Load null into ST0
    add bx, 4                   ; Move bx to point to the next float

    @@loop1:
    fadd dword ptr ss:[bx]      ; ST0 = ST0 + [BX]
    add bx, 4                   ; move the offset to point to the next input
    inc di                      ; increase the Additions Counter
    cmp di, cx                  ; if you add up all of the c++ inputs, exit loop
    jne @@loop1

    mov sp, bp
    pop bp
    ret                         ; Return value in ST0
f2 ENDP

END
```

**Build & run:**

```
PATH <Path to BCC>\BIN;<Path to TASM>\BIN
BCC.EXE main.cpp f1.asm
main.exe
```